# Show toolbar via ToolStripDropDownButton.DropDownItems?

Tags: c#, toolbar, toolstripdropdown

In my toolbar, I have a `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton` where I want to show another toolbar. I managed to get it 'working' by adding my toolbar buttons to the `DropDownItems` collection:

```
myToolbar.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[]
{
    myButton1,
    myButton2,
    myButton3
});
```

However, this produces a drop down *menu* with a lot of wasted space:

[image]

Instead of a menu, I want to show a toolbar. That is, I want my button images to be displayed side-by-side with no room for extra menu stuff (as shown above). Something like a toolbar button that says 'Command X' with a number of 'Sub command Y' items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to get the total space of the margins to disappear without creating something on your own.

You can remove the darker margins though by doing this:

```
  ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)myToolbar.DropDown).ShowCheckMargin = false;
  ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)myToolbar.DropDown).ShowImageMargin = false;
```